# Why doesn't parallel swapping work with variables in python?

Tags: python

```
lst = [0,1,2,3,4]

lst[0], lst[4] = lst[4], lst[0]

print(lst) 
#[4, 1, 2, 3, 0]
```

But, when you assign them to a variable you get a different solution.

```
lst = [0,1,2,3,4]
x = lst[0]
y = lst[4]

x,y = y,x

print(lst)
#[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(x)
# 4
print(y)
# 0
```

My best guess is that it has something to do with were the variables are pointing to in memory.

Comment: the first is a direct modification of the list, the other aren't

Comment: If you ask your neighbour his son's name so you can call yours the same, then you decide to rename him to Bob, is the neighbour's son suddenly named Bob too? Same here.

Comment: Variables are not aliases for the list elements, they just get a reference to the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the list is confusing you, so here is an equivalent example without a list:

```py
a,b = 1,2
a,b = b,a
print(a,b) # 2,1
```

vs

```py
a,b = 1,2
c,d = a,b
c,d = d,c
print(a,b) # 1,2
print(c,d) # 2,1
```

As I hope you can clearly see from the second piece of code, here we are have the values 1 and 2 in `a` and `b` respectively, and we are assigning them to `c` and `d`, and then swapping `c` and `d`. No where did we swap between `a` and `b`, so it remains `a = 1` and `b = 2`. Only `c` and `d` were swapped.